# Asp.net core in docker Unhandled exception. SqlException (0x80131904): .., but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, docker-compose, entity-framework-core, gitlab-ci

I'm getting the error

"Unhandled exception. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - Unknown error 203)"

when I start asp.net core application container using docker-compose in CI/CD flow from gitlab (self-hosted) runner on ubuntu 19.10 all docker images - latest.

After MSSQL starting i can normally connect to it using SSMS but application fails with the exception.

TargetFramework: netcoreapp3.1
ORM: EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.4

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  websiteanalyzer:
    container_name: project-aspnet-core
    image: registry.gitlab.example.com/user/project/imagename:develop
    ports:
      - "34080:34080"
    volumes:
      - /data/project/app/conf/appsettings.json:/app/appsettings.json
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    container_name: project-db
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server"
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "password"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "34433:1433"
    volumes:
      - /data/project/mssql/data:/var/opt/mssql/data
      - /data/project/mssql/log:/var/opt/mssql/log
      - /data/project/mssql/secrets:/var/opt/mssql/secrets
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
#EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
#WORKDIR /src
#COPY ["src/Project/Project.csproj", "Project/"]
#RUN dotnet restore "Project/Project.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "src/Project/Project.csproj"
#WORKDIR "/src/Project"
RUN dotnet build "src/Project/Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "src/Project/Project.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.dll"]
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=db,34433;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Any idea what might have gone wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try appending this to your connection string in *appsettings.json*:

```
Integrated Security=false;TrustServerCertificate=true
```

Such that your config is:

```
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=db,34433;Database=master;User Id=sa;Password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=false;TrustServerCertificate=true"
```

And also use aspnet:3.1-bionic in your Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:3.1-bionic
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support TLS 1.2. Update SQL Server and ensure the TLS 1.2 protocol is enabled on the server. **Or configure TLS/SSL settings in the docker image/client environment to connect with TLS 1.0.**

```
RUN sed -i 's/^MinProtocol\s*=.*$/MinProtocol = TLSv1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf && \
    sed -i 's/^CipherString\s*=.*$/CipherString = DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1/g' /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sqlclient-troubleshooting-guide?view=sql-server-ver16#possible-reasons-and-solutions